# Leibniz, beginning of Principles of Nature and Grace

Tags: metaphysics, leibniz

What did Leibniz mean at the beginning of "Principles of Nature and Grace," when he said, "Substance is a being capable of action."  Afterall, a rock is made of substances, but it is hardly active.

Answer (score 0):

See the SEP entry [Leibniz on causation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-causation/), Section 5.  Intrasubstantial Causation:

> A perception is an accident of a substance, for the action of a
> substance consists precisely in the fact that they are always changing
> their perceptions.

Concerning Leibniz' conception of *substance* see the SEP entry [Gottried Wilhelm Leibniz](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz/#LogConSub), Section 4.  Metaphysics: A Primer on Substance.